# $elemMatch is not working for version 2.6.1

Tags: mongodb, version

I have created an db with the following structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54167c9a4420660b672d2a3f"),
"a" : "1111",
"pc" : [
    [
        "bb",
        "aa",
        {
            "c" : "cc",
            "d" : "dd"
        },
        {
            "c" : "aaa",
            "d" : "ddd"
        },

    ],
    [
        "cc",
        "dd",
        {
            "a" : "cc",
            "b" : "dd"
        },
        {
            "a" : "aaa",
            "b" : "ddd"
        },
                    }
     ]
  ]
}
```

and i have used the following query in mongodb version 2.4.6, it has given the correct output

```
db.cg.find({'pc':{'$elemMatch':{'$all':['aa','bb']}}})
```

but the same query i have used in mongodb version 2.6.1 it is neither throwing any error nor giving any result

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug or missing feature with `$elemMatch`. I agree that the document should be returned by your query and I reproduce your results in MongoDB 2.4.10 (found), the latest stable 2.6.4 (not found), and the latest unstable 2.7.6 (not found). I think `$elemMatch` isn't fully implemented yet for matching non-object types (in this case, an array). Could you please [file a ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) in the Core Server project with the information in this question and then post a link to it here?

Comment: hi, @wdberkeley i have filed a ticket in core server and here is the link [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15266)